# How apply regexp_replace with unicode characters in spark hive

Tags: regex, apache-spark, hive

I'm try to count the number of occurrences of emoticons in the string in spark dataframe. 
I use SQLTransformer.
My statement:

```
select LENGTH(regexp_replace(text, '[^\\uD83C-\\uDBFF\\uDC00-\\uDFFF]+', '')) as count_emoji from __THIS__
```

But this statement doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please add more details. What is the error you are getting? What is the content of `text`?

Comment: text - is a column spark dataframe with type - string.
For example:
text = 'hello, how are you?'
This string contain three emoticons, but output a lot more three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your SQLTransform is working. Please find the code as below.

```
object SparkHiveExample extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Spark Hive Example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  //Prepare Test Data
  val df = Seq("hello, how are you?\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE0A\uD83D\uDE0A")
    .toDF("text")

  df.show(false)

+-------------------------+
|text                     |
+-------------------------+
|hello, how are you?|
+-------------------------+

  df.createOrReplaceTempView("__THIS__")

  val finalDf = spark.sql("select LENGTH(regexp_replace(text,'[^\\\\uD83C-\\\\uDBFF\\\\uDC00-\\\\uDFFF]+', '')) as count_emoji from __THIS__")

  finalDf.show(false)

+-----------+
|count_emoji|
+-----------+
|3          |
+-----------+

}
```

If you want read data from Hive table then instantiate **SparkSession** with HiveSupport and Configuration of Hive is done by placing your hive-site.xml, core-site.xml (for security configuration), and hdfs-site.xml (for HDFS configuration) file in conf/.

```
// warehouseLocation points to the default location for managed databases and tables
val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```